# How to stop Bloomberg links updating in Excel

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

I am trying to use an Excel workbook that has links to Bloomberg data in. The data has been pulled from Bloomberg already. I then want to ensure that when I send this workbook to someone that they can use the sheet without a Bloomberg terminal connection. The user without the Bloomberg feed has set calculations to manual in Excel however when they try and save the workbook it automatically tries to update the fields and gives #NAME errors in the fields where Bloomberg values should be.

Is there a way to stop Excel from trying to refresh the Bloomberg links when the workbook is saved? I have tried VBA Workbook_AfterSave and Workbook_BeforeSave events but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

A touch embarassed to admit but in Options > Formulas > Manual there is a check box for calculating the workbook before saving. I unchecked that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to the license, you're not supposed to remove values obtained using the API (Excel) from the computer where the Bloomberg Terminal is installed. That being said, if cells cease being Excel formulas they will no longer attempt to update to an up-to-date value. To do this, copy the cells that currently have a BDP/BDH formula and right click -> paste special -> values. This is also useful if you don't want the values refreshing every time you open the worksheet on the same computer.

Comment: That answer would work just fine.  I just thought I would add that you can get around the "paste special" > "paste values" if you're doing it in VBA by reassigning the values for the range of concern, i.e. `Range("A1:D20").value = Range("A1:D20").value` which will have the same effect as pasting values.